# Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having this error appears in my website.
Would you please help me to resolve the issue?
I tried to deactivate my plugins and theme, try also to downgrade my current version witch is the last one of wordpress, but still have the warning.

Thanks in advance!

> Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First
>   argument is expected to be a valid callback, '' was given in
>   /home/denivar/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 299

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: How does your code in class-wp-hook.php on line 299 looks like?

Comment: $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args ); Please let me know if i have to share more ...

Comment: check this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/broken-with-the-wordpress-4-7-update/